# jQuery doesn't respond to my click event

Tags: jquery

```
**DEVELOPMENT.JS**
jQuery(function ($) {
$("#doContact").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("ho"); // ---- It doesn't alert ----
    $("#contact-result").html('<img src="<%THEME%>images/loading.gif">');
    var formData = $("#registerForm").serialize();
    $.post("?page=register", formData, function(response)
    {
        if(response.status == 'success')
        {   
            $.modal.close();
            $('#register-success').modal({ opacity:80 });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#register-result").addClass('register-error');
            $("#register-result").html(response.error_message);
        }
    },'json');
});
});

**CONTACTFORM.HTML**
<form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post" class="centered stylish">
        <div id="contact-result">
            <div>
                <p><label for="username" class="label">Adınız:</label>
                <input id="username" placeholder="Adınız..." name="username" maxlength="20" type="text" tabindex="1" class="input" /></p>

                <p><label for="email" class="label">Email: (geri dönüş için gerekli)</label>
                <input id="email" placeholder="Email adresiniz..." name="email" maxlength="70" type="text" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" class="input"/></p>

                <p><label for="message" class="label">Mesajınız:</label>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Mesajınız..." cols="60" rows="10" name="message" maxlength="1000" type="text" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" class="input"/></p>

                <p>
                    <button id="doContact" class="ui-button button1" type="submit"> 
                        <span class="button-left">
                            <span class="button-right">Mesajımı Gönder</span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

The problem is simple.

jQuery currently works for other divs which were placed on page load. (e.g yellow login area at top right of navigation bar)

However, this form is loaded by an AJAX call so I believe I need to use functions like `delegate` or `live`. I don't know if that's the case, though.

Could you have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

```
$(document).delegate("#doContact", "click", function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$("#doContact").click(function(e) {
```

to this:

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {
```

Also change the button: `<button id="doContact"` to a submit button: `<input type="submit">`

**EDIT:**
I am not sure how you're trying to accomplish this, but this how I would do it - this works:

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // 1. Load the form.html file, and grab the form with an id of '#contactForm'
    // 2. Insert the form with id '#contactForm' into the div with id '#output'
    // 3. Submit the form
    $('#output').load('form.html #contactForm', function (html, status, xhr) {
        $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Form has been submitted!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your **form.html**

```
<div class="leftArea centered"> 
    <h2>İletişim</h2>
    <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post" class="centered stylish">
            <div>
                <p><label for="username" class="label">Adınız:</label>
                <input id="username" placeholder="Adınız..." name="username" maxlength="20" type="text" tabindex="1" class="input" /></p>

                <p><label for="email" class="label">Email: (geri dönüş için gerekli)</label>
                <input id="email" placeholder="Email adresiniz..." name="email" maxlength="70" type="text" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" class="input"/></p>

                <p><label for="message" class="label">Mesajınız:</label>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Mesajınız..." cols="60" rows="10" name="message" maxlength="1000" type="text" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" class="input"/></p>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Contact Me">
                </p>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It only works when I move jQuery into HTML file.

Comment: You're using jQuery 1.9.0 right now and live() is deprecated in that version. Try to change your jQuery version with this one: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue. Your solution works only when I move jQuery scripts into the HTML file. It doesn't work from inside a .js file. I'm not using live by the way, using delegate but it just breaks my jQuery completely.

Comment: Mate, I appreciate that you're trying to help me but there is literally no difference between doContact click function or form submit function. Tried both. It doesn't recognize it because page loads after jQuery runs. The form was inexistent when the jQuery started to run. So I need something like live or a delegate function, which keeps running when ajax calls returns something.

Comment: $(document).delegate("#doContact", "click", function() solved the issue, thank you. :)

Comment: A form does NOT submit with a click event. Forms submit with a submit event. The example I've provided works just fine!

Comment: It does. " var formData = $("#registerForm").serialize();
    $.post("?page=register", formData, function(response) " formData gets the form data and posts it to page with POST method. Also you don't seem to be understanding me so please don't bother replying...

Comment: I will repeat again: A form does NOT submit with a click event. Forms submit with a submit event. The example I've provided works just fine! Before you ask a question again, take your time to write your thoughts clearly and please choose a title that describes your problem. This title "jQuery doesn't respond to my form submit event" says that you're using a submit event. You are not! You are using a "click" event, which in return sends an AJAX POST request... Apples & Oranges! Your're doing it wrong. Please respect the fact that someone is trying to help fix YOUR problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$("#doContact").live("click",function(e) {
```

instead of

```
$("#doContact").click(function(e) {
```

This should work for the ajax loaded form